# My pyscript is not loading whenever i run the live server it downloads the pyodide.tar

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-webbrowser, pyscript, pyodide

Its stuck here

I tried Downloading the pyodide but is still gives error of
[image: example]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you open the developer console and copy/paste the error you're getting? Click on the "..." icon in the top right and under "more tools" select "developer tools", then click the "console" tab.

Comment: Don't use megapixel raster images to present a text of thirty-odd characters.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall all your internet download managers from your machine this will solve your issue. it could be IDM or anything else but you need to uninstall it. After uninstalling all your internet download managers it will start executing correctly instead of downloading the pyodide.tar.